# Combining Two different Github projects

Tags: git, github

I have a client who has multiple repos in github but two of those repos are active instances. One for production and second for staging. Our process is that we push our development on staging and if it is accepted then it is moved by their IT department to production server. This staging branch is used by 7 more vendors of the client. So there are alot of code updates from different sources.

I have a team of developers working on this project and I don't want them to push code directly on client server. I have created my own project in my github id. Everyday I take pull from client repo and push it on my account repo. At completion I take pull from my project and copy past the folders at the location where client repo is mapped. After copy paste I take pull of client repo and then push my code.

Now I have experienced that I am losing codes by this copy past process.

1). How I can improve this process?

2). Is it possible that two different locations connected with two different git accounts should update changes between each other and I can get rid of this copy past process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be much better to have a single repo and then use a branching strategy.With this branching strategy permissions should be set up so that only certain people are allowed to commit or merge into certain branches

- `master` or `main` branch would be what is live in production. This should have the fewest number of people allowed to make commits to it.  Direct commit should be rare, emergency hotfixes only. Usually it should just have merge commits
- `staging` branch should be what is live in your staging environment. Only what is about to be released to production should go in here.
- `dev` branch should contain all completed features. When a featuyre is done, it should be merged into here.
- Features/bugfix branches - All day-to-day development should be done in a branch. When completed, merge into `dev`

So that means you work on a branch like `bugfix/issue-1234`. You make a PR for it and when approved/completed it gets merged into `dev`.  At some point in time you take everything in `dev` and merge that into `staging` and deploy to that environment.  Repeat as necessary until things are correct here.  Once `staging` is good, you can merge it into `main`.

Basically you just move up the chain.  Ideally branches like `main`, `staging` and `dev` would have their own environments and any commit to these branches will trigger and automatic deployment.